# How can you edit the description, author, etc. for the built exe in MS visual C# 2008?

Tags: c#

I have finished my program in c#, hit build solution, and grabbed the exe out of the bin folder in my project directory. I noticed the description under the filename was "WindowsFormApplication1". I browsed briefly through any fields in the solutions explorer I might change, but nothing worked. Am I doing the right thing to release my program, and/or where can you change that description? I would like to just pass the exe around.

Comment: If you ever need same for native (C++) project - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975936/how-do-i-embed-version-information-into-a-windows-binary

Comment: Ah, of course you open assembly info, i was looking at the properties. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two methods.

1. Right click on project=>properties=>Application=>Assembly Information...
2. Solution Explorer=>Project=>Properties folder=>AssemblyInfo.cs

Answer (score 4):

You can change them in the project properties at `Application` -> `Assembly Information...`.
If you're concerned about the meta data in general, you may want to disable the pdb at `Build` -> `Advanced...` -> `Debug Info` or the assembly will contain the full path to the .pdb file, wich usually contains the user name.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add that in case you're working with multiple projects in one solution, one could create a separate build properties file. This way you don't need to set the properties per project.

1. Create the file `Directory.Build.Props` in the solution folder.
2. Add the following properties

   ```xml
   <Project>
       <PropertyGroup>
           <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
           <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
           <FileVersion>1.0.0.0</FileVersion>
           <Company>Stack Exchange Inc.</Company>
           <Authors>Jeff Atwood, Joel Spolsky</Authors>
           <Copyright>user contributions licensed under cc by-sa. rev 2020.10.26.37891</Copyright>
       </PropertyGroup>
   </Project>
   ```